# Doubt on women behind the development of wormhole physics

Tags: mathematicians, reference-request, physicists, gravity

Ludwig Flamm $[1]$, Albert Einstein-Natan Rosen $[2]$, Hermann Weyl $[3]$, John Wheeler-Fuller $[4,5]$, Homer G. Ellis $[6]$, K. Bronnikov $[7]$, Michael Morris-Kip Thorne$[8]$, M. Visser $[9]$, Edward Teo $[10]$, S. Kim-H.Lee $[11]$, Francisco Lobo $[12]$ and so on... are some names behind the history of wormhole physics. In particular, since the Ellis Drainhole and Morris-Thorne solutions, the physics of *traversable wormholes* have been quite active.

But, I would like to know:

> Where are the (seminal or not) papers written by women, on traversable wormhole physics? Could you give me some references?

---

$[1]$ L. Flamm, *Comments on Einstein’s Theory of Gravity* ,Physikalische Zeitschrift $17, 448, 1916$.

$[2]$ A. Einstein and N. Rosen, *The Particle Problem in the General Theory of Relativity* , Phys. Rev, $48, 1935$.

$[3]$ H. Weyl, *Philosophy of Mathematics and Natural Science*, Princeton University Press, $1949$, $p.91$.

$[4]$ J. A. Wheeler, *Geometrodynamics*, Academic Press, New York and London, $1962$.

$[5]$ R. W. Fuller and J. A. Wheeler, *Causality and Multiply-Connected Space-time* , Phys. Rev., $128, 2, 1962$.

$[6]$ H. G. Ellis, *Ether flow through a drainhole: A particle model in general relativity*, Journal of Mathematical Physics, $14, 1, 1973$.

$[7]$  K. A. Bronnikov, *Scalar-tensor theory and scalar charge*. Acta Physica Polonica. $B4: 251–266, 1973$

$[8]$ M.S. Morris and K. S. Throne, *Wormholes in General Relativity*, Am. J. Phys., $56, 5, 1988$.

$[9]$ M. Visser, *Lorentzian Wormholes*, $1995$.

$[10]$ E. Teo, *Rotating Traversable Wormholes*, arXiv:gr-qc/9803098v2, $1998$.

$[11]$ S. Kim and H. Lee, *Exact solutions of charged wormhole*, arXiv:gr-qc/0102077v1, $2001$.

$[12]$ J. P. S. Lemos, F. S. N. Lobo and S. Q. Oliveira, *Morris-Thorne wormholes with a
cosmological constant*, arXiv:gr-qc/0302049v2. $2003$

Comment: You can try a search https://arxiv.org/search/physics?query=traversable+wormhole&searchtype=all&abstracts=show&order=-announced_date_first&size=50  and  https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=traversable+wormhole  . You could also search for dissertations at universities where wormholes are studied (e.g. CalTech, UCSB, etc...)  When found, please share your findings.